# 'webdriver-manager start' step is getting stuck while executing in cmd

Tags: node.js, protractor, webdriver-manager

After installing protractor and trying to execute: `webdriver-manager start` in the command terminal, the following error is thrown:

> [17:39:27] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
>   [17:39:27] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn cmd ENOENT.

I pasted the latest chrome driver, gecko driver and selenium standalone in `npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`, So I did not execute `webdriver-manger update` within the command terminal.

I am not able to resolve this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ENOENT** errors indicate that your program wasn't able to *find the necessary entity to proceed in execution*, usually this is a file, directory, symlink, pipe, etc...

In your particular case it couldn't find: the **Selenium Standalone server binary**

This is because instead of following `protractor` [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and executing `webdriver-manager update` to *get the necessary binaries to start a Selenium server* you simply pasted the binaries in a location that you thought `protractor` would use to find said binaries. **This location is incorrect**, so you're unable to start the Selenium server properly. You can see where global `npm_modules` are installed on your system by executing a: `npm list -g`.

Typically this on `Unix` based systems this location is: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

And on `Windows`:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

In order to resolve this issue I would recommend you *follow the documentation as it's stated or search through `protractor`'s source code to see where the binaries are actually stored.*

Maybe you could try the following and see if this helps resolve your issue, **directly from their documentation:**

Use npm to install Protractor globally with:

```
npm install -g protractor
```

This will install two command line tools, `protractor` and `webdriver-manager`. Try running `protractor --version` to make sure it's working.

The `webdriver-manager` is a helper tool to *easily get an instance of a Selenium Server running. Use it to download the necessary binaries* with:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Now start up a server with:

```
webdriver-manager start
```

This will start up a Selenium Server and will output a bunch of info logs.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks Nathan.Very helpful.

Comment: Np glad it helped, best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

just add to your PATHs   C:\Windows\System32